# Semi-AutoTracking

Tags: python, tracking

I want to automatically detect features track 40 frames detect new features track 40 frames and so on.
I found this [this](https://gitlab.com/ChameleonScales/step_tracker/) addon but it does not work in 2.91.2 (I suppose my files are too heavy float EXR) so I wanted to build my own small script.
I found out how I could detect new features with python:

```
import bpy

    
C = bpy.context
ctx = C.copy()
for area in C.screen.areas:
    if area.type == 'CLIP_EDITOR':
        ctx['area'] = area

bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
```

But I can`t track them forward for x frames. I found this script but it does not work:

```
for step in range(3) :
    currFrame = (step*20)+1
    frameNumber =bpy.data.scenes["Scene"].frame_current

    area.spaces[0].clip_user.frame_current = frameNumber
    bpy.ops.clip.detect_features(ctx)
    bpy.ops.clip.track_markers(ctx, backwards = False, sequence = False)
```

[This](https://gumroad.com/l/kUxOQ) auto tracker also does not work it tracks 9 to 20 frames and then just stops.

And is there a way to prevent Blender from completely stop responding while the script does its job? Some kind of multi-threading?